# ImportError: cannot import name 'Categorical' from 'pandas.core.arrays' (unknown location)

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

Whenever i am trying to import pandas as pd
it showing

ImportError: cannot import name 'Categorical' from 'pandas.core.arrays' (unknown location)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pandas
import pandas as pd   # pandas version 1.3.5
```

it work on python version 3.7.14